# Meaning of closure in then clause in spock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spock, stubbing

We are in process of writing Unit test cases using Spock, I am not able to understand the following code snippet in then section varifying the declaration,

```
then:
1 * service.fraudMigrationOnboardingService.onboard(_) >> 
    {merchantId ->   successCallBack.call(response)}
```

what is the meaning of the above code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions without keeping people who like to help you guessing about the actual situation. You should always provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the article!). This was your free shot, I am going to answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Because your question is lacking detail, I have to speculate and make an educated guess about your test. `:-/`

- So you have a `service` with a member or getter `fraudMigrationOnboardingService`.
- `fraudMigrationOnboardingService` has a method `onboard` taking a single parameter.
- Obviously `fraudMigrationOnboardingService` is a mock or spy, which is why you can check interactions like `1 * ...` on it.
- The developer who wrote this test and whom, as it seems, you are too shy to ask about its meaning or who has left your company, wanted something specific to happen when method `onboard(_)` is called (probably by `service`) during the test: a call-back method call. Thus she declared the method stub `{ merchantId -> successCallBack.call(response) }` as a replacement for what `onboard(_)` would normally do in this case. In a spy it would execute the original method, in a mock it would no nothing at all. But obviously that is not the desired behaviour, maybe because the test relies on different behavious later on.

In general, I think a test which is hard to read should be refactored, but anyway, here I am replicating your situation:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

class DummyTest extends Specification {
  static class Service {
    FraudMigrationOnboardingService fraudMigrationOnboardingService

    void doSomething(String name) {
      println "Doing something"
      fraudMigrationOnboardingService.onboard(name)
    }
  }

  static class FraudMigrationOnboardingService {
    void onboard(String name) {
      println "On-boarding $name"
    }
  }

  static class SuccessCallBack {
    void call(int httpResponse) {
      println "Callback HTTP response = $httpResponse"
    }
  }

  def "Some service test"() {
    given:
    def onboardingService = Mock(FraudMigrationOnboardingService)
    def service = new Service(fraudMigrationOnboardingService: onboardingService)
    def successCallBack = new SuccessCallBack()
    def response = 200

    when:
    service.doSomething("ACME Inc.")

    then:
    1 * service.fraudMigrationOnboardingService.onboard(_) >>
      { merchantId -> successCallBack.call(response) }
  }
}
```

The console log says:

```
Doing something
Callback HTTP response = 200
```

If you would comment out `>> { merchantId -> successCallBack.call(response) }`, it would only print

```
Doing something
```

for a mock and if you also change the `Mock(FraudMigrationOnboardingService)` into a `Spy(FraudMigrationOnboardingService)` it would print

```
Doing something
On-boarding ACME Inc.
```

---

**Update:** Maybe you still don't understand what the closure means, I am not sure. So I will explain it a bit more: As I said, it is just a stub for the `onboard(String)` method. The method parameter is mapped to `merchantId` but not used in the stubbed method. Instead the callback is triggered.

Comment: Nice job answering this with the limited detail kriegaex